# Выравнивание div блока по центру

Tags: css

Приветствую всех еще раз за сегодня.

есть свойство у div'а, которое в css выглядит так:

```
.window { display: none; position: fixed; align:center; width: 50%; left: 25%; top:100px; border: 0px solid #888888; z-index: 10; }
```

при нажатии определенных кнопок на странице - этот блок появляется, т.е. он уже не display: none;

но т.к. у всех мониторы разные - блок имеет разную ширину. Как его можно выровнять по центру? пробовал прописывать так, но не сработало:

```
.window { display: none; position: fixed; align:center; text-align:center; top:100px; border: 0px solid #888888; z-index: 10; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Марджины должны быть на половину меньше высоты и ширины блока.
top и left всегда должен быть 50%. Этот способ описан [здесь](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/).
Если ширина и высота блока неизвестна, то можно сделать так:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var win = $('.window');
    win.css({
        'margin-top':'-' + (win.height() / 2) + 'px',
        'margin-left':'-' + (win.width() / 2) + 'px'
        });
});
```

Кстати. Не заметил, что ширина в процентах у вас. Если так то можно margin тоже задавать в процентах и тогда этот скрипт не понадобится.

Comment: все бы было хорошо, но я не знаю ширины всплывающего div'a. без этого как то выровнять можно?

Comment: @frank javascript в помощь

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Используйте отрицательные проценты в margin.

Answer (score 2):

Если размеры блока заданы процентами:

```
.window {    
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;

    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;

    top: 40%;
    bottom: 40%;
}
```